# MySQL geospatial functions to identify whether a rectangle have points in a non uniform four sided polygon and vice versa

Tags: mysql, geospatial, spatial

Inputs:
There are two inputs, both are drawn in earth's surface

- Input 1: 
  A rectangular shape, with the top left corner coordinates and bottom right corner coordinates. These coordinates are defined in latitude,longitude pairs.
- Input 2: 
  A four sided polygon(a shape strictly not a rectangle), with top left,top right,bottom left and bottom right coordinates. These coordinates are defined in latitude,longitude pairs.Data type of each value is decimal and the data is stored in a mySQL table.

How can I identify if any point inside the rectangle comes inside the polygon and vice versa using MySQL geospatial functions ?

Please see a pictorial representation at https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDju4.jpg

Comment: You are looking for [Intersects](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html#function_intersects) are you not?

Comment: Yes. But, the cases with one shape comes completely inside the other also should be handled. And the referred [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html#function_intersects) uses minimum bound rectangles rather than accurate shapes. Trying to work with a combination of mysql functions which uses [accurate object shapes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html) Thank you

Comment: Yes, sorry, the link above is old. Use ST_Intersects and ST_Contains, since 5.6, MySQL has supported proper spatial functions, not just mbr, as in the link you put in the comments. I actually was on of the beta testers, and it was so long ago, I kind of forget that mbr was even an issue, and just assume everyone knows that intersects/contains means proper polygonal functions. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from( (SELECT * FROM table WHERE ST_Intersects(geomfromtext( 'POLYGON((
                            $rectanglePoint1X $rectanglePoint1Y, $rectanglePoint2X $rectanglePoint2Y,$rectanglePoint3X
                            $rectanglePoint3Y,$rectanglePoint4X $rectanglePoint4Y,$rectanglePoint1X $rectanglePoint1Y))') , geomfromtext( 'POLYGON((
                            $polygonPoint1X $polygonPoint1Y, $polygonPoint2X $polygonPoint2Y,$polygonPoint3X
                            $polygonPoint3Y,$polygonPoint4X $polygonPoint4Y,$polygonPoint1X $polygonPoint1Y))'))) 
        union(SELECT * FROM usgs_data_repo WHERE ST_Contains(geomfromtext( 'POLYGON((
                            $rectanglePoint1X $rectanglePoint1Y, $rectanglePoint2X $rectanglePoint2Y,$rectanglePoint3X
                            $rectanglePoint3Y,$rectanglePoint4X $rectanglePoint4Y,$rectanglePoint1X $rectanglePoint1Y))') , geomfromtext( 'POLYGON((
                            $polygonPoint1X $polygonPoint1Y, $polygonPoint2X $polygonPoint2Y,$polygonPoint3X
                            $polygonPoint3Y,$polygonPoint4X $polygonPoint4Y,$polygonPoint1X $polygonPoint1Y))'))) 
        union(SELECT * FROM usgs_data_repo WHERE ST_Contains(geomfromtext( 'POLYGON((
                            $polygonPoint1X $polygonPoint1Y, $polygonPoint2X $polygonPoint2Y,$polygonPoint3X
                            $polygonPoint3Y,$polygonPoint4X $polygonPoint4Y,$polygonPoint1X $polygonPoint1Y))'),geomfromtext( 'POLYGON((
                            $rectanglePoint1X $rectanglePoint1Y, $rectanglePoint2X $rectanglePoint2Y,$rectanglePoint3X
                            $rectanglePoint3Y,$rectanglePoint4X $rectanglePoint4Y,$rectanglePoint1X $rectanglePoint1Y))') )))
```

> where { $rectanglePoint1X $rectanglePoint1Y, $rectanglePoint2X $rectanglePoint2Y,$rectanglePoint3X
>                                   $rectanglePoint3Y,$rectanglePoint4X $rectanglePoint4Y} are the co-ordinates of the rectangle(Input 1)
>
> and {$polygonPoint1X $polygonPoint1Y, $polygonPoint2X $polygonPoint2Y,$polygonPoint3X
>                                   $polygonPoint3Y,$polygonPoint4X $polygonPoint4Y} are the co-ordinates of the polygon(Input 2)
>
> Note that the above code will work in the case of any polygon instead of a rectangle as Input1